# How can we delete excel vba module when trying to see code

Tags: excel, vba

I have protected Excel VBA code with a password, which is breakable.
Now how can we delete that VBA module or code when trying to open that VBA code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You possibly can't. But did you try anything or is this "Gimme the code"

Comment: I have the code which removes the module
`ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1")`. I don't know where should I put this snippet.

Comment: Is this your question (code for removing the module, I have code for that as well). No, it is not. You are looking for a kind of event where you can hook your code in. So, what did you try so far?

Comment: Yes, I need to know where can I put this code

Comment: If you want to do that for security reason, then give up that approach. Everyone can just start Excel with macros disabled and then view your code because the macro which should delete the other macro is just disabled and won't delete it. There is no way to secure a code more than just that password.

Comment: Look at my first comment. But as you have not tried anything at all ...

Comment: I haven't tried to hook this code in any of events, as I don't know which event could be initiated.

Comment: See comment below and PEH answer: You probably can't but there seems to be software around which is able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: You just can't hide the code if someone breaks your password.

The issue is that anyone could start Excel with macros disabled. Then break your password and view your code. With macros disabled your deleting macro won't run too.

You cannot secure the code more than with that password. That's not possible.

---

The only secure way to hide code is not to include that code at VBA side:

What you can do to keep some algorithm code secret is creating a dll library (with any other language) that you then call from VBA. But that would only work for some functions like calculations but not for any code that interacts with worksheets. And the downside of this is that you would always need to give that dll along with your worksheet.

Comment: No. As I said: "*You cannot secure the code more than with that password. That's not possible.*" If it breaks, it breaks. You would just need to accept that any code you give along with VBA can be viewed if the password breaks.

Comment: So if your code is sooo top secret that your code has to be kept secret at any cost you would not use VBA anyway, and probably hire someone who has some experience in security and that field. If it is not that top secret the password would still keep +95% of the people away from viewing your code.

Comment: The answer is a PEH pointed out: You just cant hide it. But at the end there is always someone who can https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/unviewable-best-vba-project-password-protection/ But if this is working and how: I do not know. I just found it via google.

Comment: @Storax The question is just: How much can I obscure the code and how much can I confuse users who try to view it. But that's not a real security like an encryption. Because at the point where Excel should be able to run the code Excel needs to be able to decrypt it. So where the password might stop +95% this obfuscation might stop 99.9%. This might be of interest on this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: Then there is also a possibility of converting the VBA code to VSTO add-in